# Android Studio UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

Today I am faced with a massive error that doesn't let me run a sample project on my phone.

When Android Studio is building the project, it first shows the following targets as `UP-TO-DATE`:

```
....
:demoproject:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:demoproject:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:demoproject:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:demoproject:proguardDebug UP-TO-DATE
....
```

There are dozens of these `UP-TO-DATE` log statements during the build process. However, they always halt at `:demoproject:dexDebug`. For `dexDebug`, I never seem to get an `UP-TO-DATE` log statement.

Instead, `dexDebug` is followed by this error:

```
:demoproject:dexDebug
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.xyz.corp.sample.project.demo.a) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

Now there are dozens of these `Ignoring InnerClasses attribute` errors. They even occur for classes in the v4 support library, which is truly perplexing.

Finally, these errors end with a new statement:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing com/xyz/corp/sdk/AbcSDKConfig.class
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':demoproject:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:    org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
...while parsing com/xyz/corp/sdk/AbcSDKConfig.class
1 error; aborting
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
```

I have already consulted the following links:

**1.** [**Gradle finished with non-zero exit value 1**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29965398).

**2.** [**What is the “Ignoring InnerClasses attribute” warning output during compilation?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3308010/3287204).

I'm not sure they apply to my situation. I'm not even able to *run* the project. I've updated my IDE to SDK Tools 22.0.1 and modified the `buildToolsVersion` tag in my `build.gradle` file, but to no avail. Can someone please guide me how to deal with this error ? All help will be appreciated.

Oh, and here is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.corp.demo.project"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22

        versionCode 2060200
        versionName '2.6.02.00'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def file = output.outputFile
                    output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'

    compile project(':xyzSDK')
}
```

Please **HELP !!!**

Comment: can you able to restart your studio/machine, and rebuilt your project

Comment: What is your java version? 1.8? If so, roll back to 1.7

Comment: @NoName: I have described the log before the error: lots and lots of `UP-TO-DATE` statements. The `dexDebug` check doesn't get an `UP-TO-DATE` statement; it is instead followed by the above log. Is that enough for you ? And no, I haven't checked multidex issues yet ...

Comment: just noticed this in the log `com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)`  bad class file magic ?? what does this mean

Comment: please post your gradle dependencies..

Comment: @Akhil: please see my `build.gradle` in edited answer :)

Comment: Take a look at some of the answers `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866723/dx-bad-class-file-magic-cafebabe-or-version-0033-0000-with-adk14`

Comment: @Y.S. Did you find the solution for this question or shall I search more? My Answer didn't help you at all?

Comment: @Skizo: I'm sorry to say I haven't had time to return to this problem, as there is a lot of other work. I'll return to this problem soon, and lets see if your answer helps ... :)

Comment: @Skizo: I'm currently working on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32073420/3287204) ... any ideas ?

Comment: @Y.S. I've checked this question, I'm able in some hours and I'll take a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is reporting: `bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)` you should check if you are compiling with the same java version that you are trying to use at runtime.
If you are using gradle you should use the following or similar entries in your build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
```

Use this [link](http://www.alonsoruibal.com/my-gradle-tips-and-tricks/) for more gradle details.

In Android Studio, from `File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK Location` you should use the jdk 1.7 and not relay on the `Project level` setting. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662801/bad-class-file-magic-or-version) for a similar Android Studio question.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the answer. Let me try it out and get back to you ... :)

Comment: In the meantime, I have a question. I have to integrate this SDK into my main project which uses Java 1.8, and I would prefer that it remain that way. Is there no way I can compile this project with 1.8 ??

Comment: You should be able to compile using 1.8 but the `targetCompatibility` should be set to 1.7. This way the binaries will be 1.7 compatible.

Comment: so you mean in Project Structure I can point to JDK 1.8, and set `targetCompatibility` and `sourceCompatibility` to 1.7, and it will work ?

Comment: Yes, if the build is managed by gradle, using `targetCompatibility ` set to 1.7, it will produce 1.7 compatible binaries.

Comment: Currently it is giving an error `Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.` Every time I try to sync this project with Gradle, it gives the same error :(

Comment: That means that you already have the 'java' plugin registered in you gradle.build file. But have you tried in Android Studio to use jdk1.7 or Android API 20, at least?

Comment: I am going to try what you said first: to manually point the IDE to JDK 1.7. Let me see if I am at least able to run the program. and I will get back to you ... :)

Answer (score 1):

`UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION` means that you are getting included twice any `.jar`.

As @Akhil said you should exclude `support-v4` because I guess it's the main problem, but if @Akhil answer didn't help you try it out this method.

```
compile (':xyzSDK') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Have you tried to delete this line?

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
```

Maybe `:xyzSDK` allready has `appcompat-v7:22+`..

I give you there a [good answer by @CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100040/4385913) to make a gradle report to see what's the problem.

I'm working for your answer, so if I find something interessant I'll be updating my answer.

Once you've done this you **must** `Build -> Rebuild project`

Also as I saw on @dan answer... I let you there a possible [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741948/wrong-java-compiler-when-including-a-java-module-as-dependency-in-android-studio).

Instead of `1.7` as dan said try to :

```
compileOptions {

    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Otherwise you can check it manually going to `File > Project Structure` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then on the `JDK location` see what are you using and if you are using 1.8 change to your 1.7 SDK path

And btw I think that I've read that you have asked if you could use `JAVA 8` for Android instead of `JAVA 7` if i'm not wrong.... and yes you could use `JDK 8`, but only if you also use `gradle-retrolamba` like says on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)..

Comment: I am accepting this answer for now, but I am not yet done with it. I need to re-check this problem and do some more research ... :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your **libs** folder & library project **xyzSDK** contains same library, which is causing issues while converting to dex

You can try to identify such library and remove it from one place.
Or excluding it like this

```
compile project(':xyzSDK'){
      exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

I have taken example of **support-v4**, as i have faced similar issues due to this one previously.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This could indeed be the problem. Were you getting the exact same error as I am due to this ??