# Android nine patch - allow only a specific area of a background drawable to stretch

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view, android-drawable

How does one go about creating a `View` that has boundaries with triangular perforations ?

[image]

I've been using background drawables to achieve this so far. That works when the dimensions of the `View` are fixed. Now I have a situation where the *height* of the `View` is not constant, so I need to have the height variable on the fly. I can't use a background drawable with a fixed height anymore.

Here is the original background drawable:

[image]

And this is what the final `View` needs to look like:

[image]

Another way of looking at the same problem is, can we allow the center of the image to stretch without distorting the boundaries ? If we could do this, we could use the existing drawable as a background.

How can this be achieved ? Has anyone else faced this problem before ? Does the framework have an existing way of dealing with this class of problems ?

Comment: I would like to follow this question.

Comment: If you want to stick to using a background drawable, have you tried a 9patch?

Comment: Would it be possible to vary the height of the drawable if I use a 9-patch ? Please elaborate ...

Comment: Share the image that you use right now. Ill make an example. 9patch images were designed to allow you to scale in all directions, by your own specifications.

Comment: That is a screengrab of your image isn't it? I am talking about your *actual* image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a normal image, you can generate a nine-patch png.

Use [`Simple Nine-patch Generator`](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) for this.

The trick is the black line on the left side. That tells Android that the png is vertically expandable along this area.

Please see this example:

[image: Nine Patch Example]

Save it as a nine-patch, in the format imagename.9.png

Comment: When trying to build the project, I'm getting an error: No marked region found along edge.

Comment: There are some good generators online, such as this one: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Comment: It probably needs the top edge to have a full black line too to indicate that the entire width stretches. Ill add that.

Comment: I'm sure you can manage to do that yourself. The question itself has been answered.

Comment: I have this same question. The problem I still have with this solution is that the entire width is being allowed to stretch. The question is how to maintain the aspect ratio of the entire width and non-stretchable top and bottom portions of the height, but still allow the middle portion to stretch only in the vertical direction. Like @Y.S. points out, the compiler won't allow for no stretchable region marked in the horizontal direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *NinePatch  image* as drawable of that view. To learn how to create a NinePatch  image, goto [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Answer (score 1):

The 9 patch mechanism didn't work to do something similar for my use case, because it requires a stretchable region to be defined in both the horizontal and vertical directions. The 9 patch will only work if the `ImageView` is able to be constrained to the exact width of the source drawables, to avoid any horizontal stretching.

If the view needs to be allowed to stretch horizontally, maintaining the aspect ratio of the top and bottom boundary portions of the image, while the middle portion is allowed to stretch freely in both directions, a 9 patch won't work for this. I created this layout to accomplish this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/image_top" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageMiddle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/image_middle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/image_bottom" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*image_top.png*
[image]

*image_middle.png*
[image]
(Note, this image could be shrunk to as little as 1 pixel high, if the subtle gray gradient on the right isn't necessary.)

*image_bottom.png*
[image]

The key is having `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` on the boundary images, while the drawables are specified with `android:src`. Then the middle image specifies the drawable with `android:background` and resizes to fill the height of the parent layout with `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`.

`android:scaleType="fitXY"` was necessary in addition in order to force a final scaling of the images after their view bounds are adjusted to handle any potential tiny pixel differences in alignment on hi-res displays. They are all resized to fill their bounds completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a zigzag path in background of your view

```
Rect rectZigzag = new Rect();
private Path pathZigzag = new Path();
private Paint paintZigzag;
private void init(){
    this.paintZigzag = new Paint();
    this.paintZigzag.setColor(zigzagBackgroundColor);
    this.paintZigzag.setStyle(Style.FILL);
}


private void drawZigzag() {
    float left = rectZigzag.left;
    float right = rectZigzag.right;
    float top = rectZigzag.top;
    float bottom = rectZigzag.bottom;
    int width = (int) (right - left);

    pathZigzag.moveTo(right, bottom);
    pathZigzag.lineTo(right, top);
    pathZigzag.lineTo(left, top);
    pathZigzag.lineTo(left, bottom);

    int h = zigzagHeight;
    int seed = 2 * h;
    int count = width / seed;
    int diff = width - (seed * count);
    int sideDiff = diff / 2;


    float x = (float) (seed / 2);
    float upHeight = bottom - h;
    float downHeight = bottom;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int startSeed = (i * seed) + sideDiff + (int) left;
        int endSeed = startSeed + seed;

        if (i == 0) {
            startSeed = (int) left + sideDiff;
        } else if (i == count - 1) {
            endSeed = endSeed + sideDiff;
        }

        this.pathZigzag.lineTo(startSeed + x, upHeight);
        this.pathZigzag.lineTo(endSeed, downHeight);
    }
}
```

[refrence](https://github.com/beigirad/ZigzagView)

Comment: can you just copy and paste a piece of your code here?

Comment: its a customViewgroup that gets you height of tiny zigzags and calculate number of zigzags and you can use shadow/elevation.
if you see this link, find dependencies and know how implement that.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18754689)

Comment: hey dear moderator I changed my answer, please take back your downvote to getting out from ban answer, I can't edit and undelete other answer until my reputation score is under 5 @TommasoBelluzzo